# OpenCV Sobel Filter with ksize=1

Tags: opencv, filter, kernel, computer-vision

I have this question of filtering using Sobel kernel. I know basically it is square-shaped such as the 3x3 x here

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

However, the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#sobel) mentioned that when the `ksize` parameter is set to 1, the filter will be of 1x3 or 3x1 (1-D filter) yet it didn't tell how the filter is.

Is it (for x) like `[-1 0 1]` or `[-2 0 2]`? How is it any of these? Sorry I may not understand how Sobel affect on signals, but I'd appreciate if someone explained to me that :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sobel operator is separable:

```
[-1 0 1      [1
 -2 0 2  =    2  * [-1 0 1]
 -1 0 1]      1]
```

Given an image `A`,

```
Gx = [1 2 1]'*([-1 0 1] * A);
```

Comment: Sounds great, thank you! So if the case is ksize=1 it means that

Gx=[-1 0 1]* A

Comment: Yes, and I think the minimum filter size is 2X1 because [1 2 1]'=convolution ([1 1], [1 1]')